# Composition of two Riemannian isometries

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry

Whilst studying Riemanninan charts, I tried to prove the statement that the composition of two Riemanninan isometries is still a Riemanninan isometry. Let me elaborate:

Say we have a Riemanninan chart $(P,g)$ together with two Riemannian isometries $A$ and $B$, both from $(P,g) \to (P,g)$. Then I would like to prove that $A \circ B$ is also a Riemannian isometry from $(P,g) \to (P,g)$.

So if I'm understanding this correctly, I have $A: (P,g) \to (P,g)$ and $B: (P,g) \to (P,g)$. It seems to be obvious that their composition also maps from $(P,g) \to (P,g)$? Could someone maybe help me how to elaborate on this?

Comment: Do you know what $A : (P, g) \to (P, g)$ means (beyond being a map $P \to P$)?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I think so, since A and B both are differentiable bijections which also have a differentiable inverse, right?

Comment: None of what you said has anything to do with $g$ though. You're missing a condition.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ah I see. The metric g must be preserved right?

Comment: Yes. How would you express the metric being preserved?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Is it that $A^*(g)=g$ ? By which I mean the pullback of A w.r.t. g.

Comment: Yes, although I would just write $A^*g = g$. We also have $B^*g = g$. What do we need for $A\circ B$ to be a Riemannian isometry then?

Comment: I also recommend writing this in local coordinates. Even if you are able to prove it using pullbacks, you should know what it looks like under the hood.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese For their composition, we then would have $(A \circ B)^* g = g$ ?

Comment: Exactly. So what you need to do is show that if $A^*g = g$ and $B^*g = g$, then $(A\circ B)^*g = g$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ah alright! And I would prove this using the definition of the pullback and working it out?

Comment: Sure, but you'd just be proving a special case of a general relationship between $(A\circ B)^*$, $A^*$, and $B^*$. Do you know what this relationship is?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Hm no I'm not sure?

Comment: It is $(A\circ B)^* = B^*\circ A^*$. Given that you didn't know this, you should try to prove it for yourself.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Hi again, I tried to come up with the proof and posted it as an answer. Could you maybe, if possible ofcourse, take a look? Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hints I got in the comments, I tried to complete the proof:

We have our Riemannian chart $(P,g)$ with two isometries $A,B$ from $(P,g) \to (P,g)$.
Since $A$ and $B$ are Riemannian isometries, the metric will be preserved. Hence, $A^*g=g$ and $B^*g=g$.

$(A \circ B)^* = B^* \circ A^*$, and therefore
$(A \circ B)^*g=g$, making the composition a Riemanninan isometry.

Comment: I would put in a couple of intermediate steps to make the equality $(A\circ B)^*g = g$ absolutely clear. That is, I think writing $(A\circ B)^*g = (B^*\circ A^*)g = B^*(A^*g) = B^*g = g$ is preferable.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be part of this answer, but you should make sure you know why $(A\circ B)^* = B^*\circ A^*$.

Comment: @Deane Im gonna try to figure that out, thank you!